# How to get the values of column in SQL comma separated

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Hi my original data is as below

```
Id   | Value
-----+------
0001 | IN
0001 | ME
0001 | OH
0001 | ON
0002 | AC
0002 | ON
0002 | VI
0002 | ZO
0003 | ME
0003 | OO
0003 | PS
0003 | QA
```

Wanted to get the Data in

```
Id   | Value
-----+------
0001 | IN,ME,OH,ON
0002 | AC,ON,VI,ZO
0003 | ME,OO,PS,QA
```

in SQL server 2008

Comment: I have tested the query in sql server ,,, it's work well you can utilize the answer, and dont forget the answer to mark as correct so it can help other in future.

Answer (score 0):

This will work :

```
  SELECT
  t1.ID,
  MemberList = substring((SELECT ( ', ' + Value )
                       FROM your_table t2
                       WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID
                       ORDER BY 
                          ID,
                          Value
                       FOR XML PATH( '' )
                      ), 3, 1000 )FROM your_table t1
   GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    drop table #t
    
create table #t(id varchar(10),value char(10))

insert into #t values('0001','IN'),
('0001','ME'),
('0001','OH'),
('0001','ON'),
('0002','AC'),
('0002','ON'),
('0002','VI'),
('0002','ZO'),
('0003','ME'),
('0003','OO'),
('0003','PS'),
('0003','QA')

select distinct id,
    stuff((select ',' + CAST(t2.Value as varchar(10))
     from #t t2 where t1.id = t2.id 
     for xml path('')),1,1,'') as Value
from #t t1
group by id,Value
```

Output:

[image]

## [See Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/14631)