# What is the meaning of SELECT ... FOR XML PATH(' '),1,1)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am learning sql in one of the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21604129/how-to-get-the-values-of-column-in-sql-comma-seprated/21604634#21604634) [and here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d4bc611f-0951-4ed6-9634-c204b2304f92/stuff-and-for-xml-path) I saw usage of this,can some body make me understand what xml path('') mean in sql? and yes,i browsed through web pages I didn't understand it quite well!

I am not getting the Stuff behind,now what does this piece of code do ?(only `select` part)

```
declare @t table
(
    Id int,
    Name varchar(10)
)
insert into @t
select 1,'a' union all
select 1,'b' union all
select 2,'c' union all
select 2,'d' 

select ID,
stuff(
(
    select ','+ [Name] from @t where Id = t.Id for XML path('')
),1,1,'') 
from (select distinct ID from @t )t
```

Comment: the 1,1) in your question header is `stuff` parameter! stuff takes 4 parameters stuff(@expr,start,len,replacement) so sub query is the expression,starting at positin 1,lenght 1,then replace with `''`

Comment: Yes.  It was confusing..  In lot of places I was seeing this the empty SQL string ('') looks just like it was a single double quote ("), so it looks like you are passing "), 1, 1,"  to path().

Answer (score 71):

There's no real technique to learn here. It's just a cute trick to concatenate multiple rows of data into a single string. It's more a quirky use of a feature than an intended use of the `XML` formatting feature.

```
SELECT ',' + ColumnName ... FOR XML PATH('')
```

generates a set of comma separated values, based on combining multiple rows of data from the `ColumnName` column. It will produce a value like `,abc,def,ghi,jkl`.

```
STUFF(...,1,1,'')
```

Is then used to remove the leading comma that the previous trick generated, see [`STUFF`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) for details about its parameters.

(Strangely, a lot of people tend to refer to this method of generating a comma separated set of values as "the STUFF method" despite the `STUFF` only being responsible for a final bit of trimming)

Comment: ok..and what does `FOR XML PATH( '' )
                      ), 3, 1000 )` mean?

Comment: @george - it's difficult to tell without seeing the larger query. As I hoped was obvious from what I've said in my answer, the `FOR XML PATH('')` and anything that occurs beyond it are part of two *different* tricks or usages, and you need to look earlier in the query to work out what function is being passed the `, 3, 1000` parameters.

Answer (score 31):

SQL you were referencing is used for string concatenation in `MSSQL`.

It concatenates rows by prepending `,` using `for xml path` to result
`,a,b,c,d`. Then using `stuff` it replaces first `,` for , thus removing it.

The `('')` in `for xml path` is used to remove wrapper node, that is being automatically created. Otherwise it would look like `<row>,a,b,c,d</row>`.

```
...
stuff(
  (
  select ',' + CAST(t2.Value as varchar(10)) from #t t2 where t1.id = t2.id 
  for xml path('')
  )
,1,1,'') as Value
...
```

- more on [stuff](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx)
- more on [for xml path](http://sqlandme.com/2011/04/27/tsql-concatenate-rows-using-for-xml-path/)

Comment: Here is a nice example application of this technique: [Dynamic Pivoting](http://pratchev.blogspot.com/2008/12/dynamic-pivoting.html)

Comment: @David mentioned link is not exist anymore!

Comment: @QMaster - I just verified it does Zen of SQL : Dynamic Pivoting http://pratchev.blogspot.com/2008/12/dynamic-pivoting.html

Comment: where Id = t.Id   can anybody explain this part of code ?? Is it a sort of group by??