# Concatenate Two Separate Columns of Text Per ID

Tags: sql-server

I know it's possible to concatenate one row using the following code. For example making one row of StudentName text per subject ID.

Example Data

```
  Patient_FIN       StudentName
  ----------      -------------
  1               Mary
  1               John
  2               Alaina
  2               Edward
```

Expected Results

```
 Patient_FIN       StudentName
 ----------      -------------
 1               Mary, John
 2               Alaina, Edward
```

Code used to get the above output

```
SELECT DISTINCT ST2.pt_fin, 
        SUBSTRING(
                 (
            SELECT ST1.StudentName + ',' AS [text()]
            FROM ED_ORDERS_IMPORT_MASTER ST1
            WHERE ST1.Patient_FIN = ST2.Patient_FIN
            ORDER BY ST1.Patient_FIN
            FOR XML PATH ('')
        ) , 2, 1000) [Patient]
      FROM ED_ORDERS_IMPORT_MASTER ST2
```

However, let's say I have the same data and an additional row that I'd also like to concatenate into a separate column based on Patient_FIN:

```
   Patient_FIN       StudentName    Color
  ----------      -------------   ----------
    1               Mary           Blue  
    1               John           Red
    2               Alaina         Red
    2               Edward         White
```

Desired Results

```
 Patient_FIN       StudentName         Color
 ----------      -------------       ----------
 1               Mary, John           Blue, Red
 2               Alaina, Edward       Red, White
```

How can I edit the above code to produce the desired results? Thanks!

Comment: It is the same exact concept. You know how to get the data for StudentName, rinse and repeat to get the data for Color.

Comment: I would suggest replacing `SUBSTRING` with `STUFF` too, and **replacing** the first character with `''` instead.

Comment: So I added an additional line of code under the first select command "ST1.Color + ',' AS [text()]". This concatenates the color column but adds it to the name column (I want the color column to be independent of the name column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use STUFF to get your desired output as below-

```
SELECT Patient_FIN,
STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT ',' + StudentName 
        FROM your_table 
        WHERE Patient_FIN = A.Patient_FIN
        FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, ''
) StudentName,
STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT ',' + Color 
        FROM your_table 
        WHERE Patient_FIN = A.Patient_FIN
        FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, ''
) Color
FROM your_table A
GROUP BY Patient_FIN
```

Output is-

```
Patient_FIN StudentName     Color
1           Mary,John       Blue,Red
2           Alaina,Edward   Red,White
```

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake there is no error-thanks! Brilliant code!

Comment: Out of curisoity what does the command do for the code? FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, ''

Comment: That's part of STUFF method.

Comment: so what is the  "('')), 1, 1, " telling code to do?

Comment: You will get some details here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21623593/what-is-the-meaning-of-select-for-xml-path-1-1